# Why Not looking for the View in the correct location

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm an MVC newbie so this might sound trivial.I have my 2 Views(EnterLogin.aspx,ShowLogin.aspx) in a folder called `LoginForm` in Views.
Here is my Global.asax.cs below

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "LoginForm", action = "ShowLogin", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

Here is my ShowLogin.aspx design code

```
<form method="post" action="EnterLogin" runat="server">
    Hello, i'm login page
    Enter Name   <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <input type="submit" value="PressMe" />
</form>
```

Here are my controllers

```
public class LoginFormController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ShowLogin()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult EnterLogin()
    {
        return View("EnterLogin");
    }
}
```

On running the application it first loads with url

```
http://localhost:50224/
```

and shows the ShowLogin.aspx View

On clicking the button I'm calling `EnterLogin` controller to show `EnterLogin` View but it looks in URL

```
http://localhost:50224/EnterLogin
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:50224/LoginForm/EnterLogin
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: You have no other routes defined? (Just the ignore and default routes in Global?) Also, how are you generating that `EnterLogin` link--using `@Html.ActionLink`/`@Html.RouteLink` or just `<a href="/EnterLogin">...`?

Comment: how about the second part of the comment--how are you creating a link to that action? Also, you should keep `HomeController` as your default and use the `<authentication>` portion of your `web.config` to re-route to the login page (when necessary) instead of having the client default to the login page.

Comment: i'm posting the form with action="EnterLogin"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're not landing where you want to is the `action` portion of your form:

```
action="EnterLogin"
```

This should follow the correct route to ensure it hits the `LoginFormController`. e.g.

```
action="/LoginForm/EnterLogin"
```

Remember that the incoming request needs to match a route specified in `RegisterRoutes`. Because you don't have anything directly matching `EnterLogin` it will try to use `EnterLogin` to fill in the `{controller}` then default to `ShowLogin` as the action (resulting in a failed request). basically:

```
EnterLogin  ==resolves==>  EnterLogin  /ShowLogin/
                           {controller}/{action} /{id}
```

Alternatively you can make a named route that will redirect to the correct location if you want to short-hand it:

```
action="LogMeIn"
```

and then:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Login",
    "LogMeIn",
    new { controller = "LoginForm", action = "EnterLogin" }
);
```

Now requesting `/LogMeIn` will execute `LoginForm`'s `EnterLogin()` action.

Answer (score 0):

The default route defined in Global.asax defines routes which have /controller/action.

Your controller is called LoginForm and your action is called EnterLogin so this is expected behaviour.

If you want to exclude LoginForm from the URL, you need to define a custom route to allow for this.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        "LoginForm_EnterLogin", // Route name
        "LoginForm/EnterLogin/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "LoginForm", action = "ShowLogin", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like this

Global.asax.cs :-

> 

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "LoginForm", action = "ShowLogin", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

ShowLogin.aspx :-

```
 <form method="post" action="EnterLogin" runat="server">
     Hello, i'm login page
    Enter Name   <input type="text" name="txtName"/>
     <input type="submit" value="PressMe" /> </form>
```

LoginFormController :-

```
public class LoginFormController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ShowLogin()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EnterLogin(FormCollection collection)
    {
        string Yourtxtname=Collection["txtName"]; //You will get input text value

        return View();
    }
}
```